# Is there any special reason to use the character "k" standing for the "early"?

Tags: applied-econometrics

From the paper of [Bacon,2018, p.5](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w25018/w25018.pdf), I saw a paragraph as below

> The simplest way to illustrate how treatment timing works is to
> consider a balanced panel dataset with  periods () and 
> cross-sectional units () that belong to either an untreated group,
> ; an early treatment group, , which receives a binary treatment at
>  * ; and a late treatment group, ℓ, which receives the binary
> treatment at  * ℓ >  *

In this paragraph, I am curious if "*k*" stand for any word having the meaning "early". For example, "l" is late, "U" is untreated,...

Answer (score 2):

You can write the author to know for sure, without this one can only speculate.

I don't think the solution is that there is a word for early that starts with a k. Rather people do not like to use $e$, as it has a meaning as [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), while $i,j,k,l$ are pretty standard indexing letters.